# Content Query Web Parts are not showing up in pages with the Page Layout they are set to

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part, page-layout

I'am back again with another question.
I have a Pagelayout and want to add a Content Query Webpart as Menu.
I created a Webpartzone and added a Webpart.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="g_91F45F969948455D914881221F1D2D85" runat="server" title="Zone 1">
<PublishingWebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart runat="server" DataSourceID="" ChromeType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" ListUrl="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PageSize="-1" IsIncludedFilter="" ViewContentTypeId="" IsVisible="True" Title="Content Query" ZoneID="" AutoRefresh="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ManualRefresh="False" ExportControlledProperties="True" ItemStyle="Default" ID="g_61e6b0bf_4133_49bd_b271_63ef74c6a695" ServerTemplate="" FrameState="Normal" PartOrder="2" ShowWithSampleData="True" AllowHide="False" SortBy="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}" ViewFlag="0" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" PartImageLarge="" DataMappings="Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|Description:{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},ShortComment,Text;|ImageUrl:{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|LinkUrl:{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},FileRef,Lookup;|" AllowMinimize="False" AsyncRefresh="False" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Dir="Default" AllowZoneChange="True" PartImageSmall="" GroupStyle="DefaultHeader" IsIncluded="True" DetailLink="" Description="Displays a dynamic view of content from your site." SortByDirection="Desc" ExportMode="All" AllowEdit="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowConnect="True" ListId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowRemove="False" NoDefaultStyle="" HelpLink="" ListDisplayName="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{61e6b0bf-4133-49bd-b271-63ef74c6a695}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="" DataMappingViewFields="{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},Lookup;{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},Text;" ContentTypeBeginsWithId="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D0026240B8F6727B74EB440B3C7C398ACB6" ShowUntargetedItems="False" GroupByDirection="Desc">
    <DataFields>
</DataFields><SampleData>
<dsQueryResponse>
                    <Rows>
                        <Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True" __begingroup="True" />
                        <Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" />
                    </Rows>
                    </dsQueryResponse></SampleData><Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x"> <xsl:import href="/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/Header.xsl" /> <xsl:import href="/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /> <xsl:import href="/Style%20Library/XSL%20Style%20Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /> </xsl:stylesheet></Xsl>
</PublishingWebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart>

</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

I enabled Demo-Mode.. tried exporting a existing webpart but nothing works..
I can see the CQWP in the Designer but not on the Webpage.. Yes i am editing the right :P, if i just type something and save it comes up...

Why is there nothing? Not even an error-message? If in set up the CQWP in the Browser this works.. but i have more then 10 Pages on which i need that..

Comment: Does it show when you create a new page form that page layout? Even without the ZoneTemplate as mentioned below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot the **ZoneTemplate** tag.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone PartChromeType="None" ID="Zone1" runat="server" Title="Zone1"> 
        <ZoneTemplate> 
                <MyTag:MyWebPart runat="server" PartOrder="1" ></MyTag:MyWebPart> 
        </ZoneTemplate> 
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```